# Trying to build a museum-like system, where a button press triggers some video and audio. Have absolutely no idea where to start with the buttons

Tags: gpio

I want to place around 20 buttons onto a wall, which will then make the Raspberry Pi send a signal to a laptop, to start playing a certain video and audio file. I've had very little experience with Raspberry Pi's overall.

My biggest issue is finding the correct buttons, and how to connect them. Every guide I find online tells me how to connect some tiny buttons on a breadboard with the Pi, but nothing about how to actually do something practical. Maybe I just don't know what I'm exactly looking for, but so far I've come up with nothing.

What would be my best approach for this?

Thank you

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: `Raspberry Pi send a signal to a laptop` ... why not have the RPi play the video?

Comment: why is your question saying `museum like system`, when it should be saying `how to detect button press`? ... please focus on the actual problem, not on the whole project

Comment: *"but nothing about how to actually do something practical"* -> Turning an led on and off is something practical, there must be scores of tutorials about that online.   However, the "doing something" and the fact it should be triggered by a button do not necessarily have anything to do with one another, which is the point of the microprocessor in the middle:  You can detect a button is pressed and then do whatever you like.  Don't bother trying to research these things in tandem.   You need to know 1) How to detect a button press; 2) How to do whatever it is you then want done.